# Why does Windows 7 not allow me to format all of my 3rd 3TB drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I had a 3TB drive and it crashed, so I am replacing it now.

But, after installing it and booting to Windows, in `Computer Management > Disk Management`, firstly it is already partitioned into 2 a 2TB partition and a 760GB. But more importantly, it doesn't allow me to format the smaller partition.

Ideally, I would have just 1 large partition. It won't allow me to delete that partition.

Is there a maximum hard drive size limit I have hit upon? I doubt that, because I had 3 3TB drives before....so it shouldn't be an issue...right?

In total, I have 1 240GB SSD, 1 150GB 15K RPM, 3 3TB 7200rpm drives.

How do I fix this?

See screenshots below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Use GPT instead of MBR

Comment: How do I format it as GPT instead of MBR within Windows? I am not seeing the option within this Disk Management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Ramhound, try converting the disk to GPT. From within Disk Management, select the whole disk and right click. (The box on the left, where it says "Disk #"). Then convert to GPT disk. If the Windows Disk Management tool is insufficient, try [GParted](http://gparted.org/), a very powerful linux-based partition manager that can tackle any and every storage management job.

Comment: Perfect dude. Right clicking on the Disk # did it. Thanks mucho. That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @marcamillion No problem. Happy to help.